# Spotify - is there a way to programmatically set a track starred value to true?

Tags: spotify

My object is defined like this:

```
var myTrack = models.Track.fromURI('spotify:track:0123456789');
```

How do I set the starred value to true? Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

`models.library.starredPlaylist.add(models.Track.fromURI('spotify:track:0123456789'));`

Comment: That works fine however when I add a track to the starred playlist and then I query the track again with models.Track.fromURI(...), the starred value is still false. But if I restart the spotify application and query that song THEN the value is true.